# Colour-model classes using CRTP

Tags: c++, inheritance, template-meta-programming, overloading, color

I want to implement [color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) logic.

So I started with creating some structs:

```
struct RGB {
    unsigned char r,g,b;
};

struct ARGB {
    unsigned char a,r,g,b;
};

struct HSL {
    float h,s,l;
};

struct Lab {
    float l,a,b;
};
```

As you can see, I have different color spaces  in my program: the [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) and [CIEXYZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space).
Then I realized that I have to do operator overloading for all of the structs (color models), so I started thinking about creating a *base `struct ColorModel`* which has to somehow do all the operator overloading. But I can't have any virtual functions => pointers to `vtable`, as it will increase the size of any pixel and imagine what will be the size of a picture in my ram? So I decided to do some `template metaprogramming`, [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to be more specific. I created my base struct like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

namespace color_space {
template<int Space, typename T, typename C>
struct ColorModel {
    
    static constexpr int SPACE = Space;
    
    ColorModel() {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), 0);
    };
    
    ColorModel(const ColorModel& other) {
        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
    }
    
    ColorModel(ColorModel&& other) noexcept {
        std::move(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
    }
    
    ColorModel(const std::initializer_list<T>& l) {
        std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), begin());
    }
    
    explicit ColorModel(const T& elem) {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), elem);
    }
    
    const T* cbegin() const {
        return static_cast<const C*>(this)->components.cbegin();
    }
    
    const T* cend() const {
        return static_cast<const C*>(this)->components.cend();
    }
    
    const T* begin() const {
        return cbegin();
    }
    
    const T* end() const {
        return cend();
    }
    
    T* begin() {
        return static_cast<C*>(this)->components.begin();
    }
    
    T* end() {
        return static_cast<C*>(this)->components.end();
    }
    
    size_t size() const {
        return std::distance(begin(), end());
    }
    
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const {
        return *(begin() + i);
    }
    
    T& operator[](unsigned int i) {
        return *(begin() + i);
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator=(const ColorModel& rhs) {
        std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator=(ColorModel&& rhs) noexcept {
        std::move(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator=(const T& rhs) {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), rhs);
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator=(T&& rhs) noexcept {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), rhs);
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator+=(const ColorModel& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::plus<>());
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator+=(ColorModel&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::plus<>());
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator+=(const T& rhs) {
        std::for_each(begin(), end(), [&](T& elem) { elem += rhs; });
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator+=(T&& rhs) {
        std::for_each(begin(), end(), [&](T& elem) { elem += rhs; });
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator-=(const ColorModel& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::minus<>());
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator-=(ColorModel&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::minus<>());
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator-=(const T& rhs) {
        std::for_each(begin(), end(), [&](T& elem) { elem -= rhs; });
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator-=(T&& rhs) {
        std::for_each(begin(), end(), [&](T& elem) { elem -= rhs; });
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator*=(const ColorModel& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator*=(ColorModel&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator*=(const T& rhs) {
        std::for_each(begin(), end(), [&](T& elem) { elem *= rhs; });
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator*=(T&& rhs) {
        std::for_each(begin(), end(), [&](T& elem) { elem *= rhs; });
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator/=(const ColorModel& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::divides<>());
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator/=(ColorModel&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::divides<>());
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator/=(const T& rhs) {
        std::for_each(begin(), end(), [&](T& elem) { elem /= rhs; });
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel& operator/=(T&& rhs) {
        std::for_each(begin(), end(), [&](T& elem) { elem /= rhs; });
        return *this;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator+(const ColorModel& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::plus<>());
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator+(ColorModel&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::plus<>());
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator+(const T& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
#pragma clang loop vectorize(enable)
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            result[i] = (*this)[i] + rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator+(T&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
#pragma clang loop vectorize(enable)
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            result[i] = (*this)[i] + rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator-(const ColorModel& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::minus<>());
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator-(ColorModel&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::minus<>());
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator-(const T& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
#pragma clang loop vectorize(enable)
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            result[i] = (*this)[i] - rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator-(T&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
#pragma clang loop vectorize(enable)
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            result[i] = (*this)[i] - rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator*(const ColorModel& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator*(ColorModel&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator*(const T& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
#pragma clang loop vectorize(enable)
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            result[i] = (*this)[i] * rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator*(T&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
#pragma clang loop vectorize(enable)
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            result[i] = (*this)[i] * rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator/(const ColorModel& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::divides<>());
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator/(ColorModel&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::divides<>());
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator/(const T& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
#pragma clang loop vectorize(enable)
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            result[i] = (*this)[i] / rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    ColorModel operator/(T&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
#pragma clang loop vectorize(enable)
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
            result[i] = (*this)[i] / rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    
    bool operator==(const ColorModel& rhs) const {
        return std::equal(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    }
    
    bool operator!=(const ColorModel& rhs) const {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }
    
    
};

template<int Space, typename T, typename C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ColorModel<Space, T, C>& space) {
    for (const T& component: space) {
        os << component << " ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

And my structs will be implemented like this:

```
struct RGB : ColorModel<0,unsigned char, RGB> {
    union {
        std::array<unsigned char,3> components;
        struct {
             unsigned char r,g,b;
        }
    }

    // Base constructors call 
};
```

I would be very grateful if you review this implementation of operator overloading.

P.S. The first argument `int Space` in the template argument list will be used after. I am going to write a logic to convert from one space to another, but that is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's safe to `union` a standard array and a struct like that.  I would make `r`, `g` and `b` be member *functions* instead:

```
unsigned char& r() { return components[0]; }
unsigned char const& r() const { return components[0]; }
```

(You could make `r`, `g` and `b` members be references into `components`, but compilers might reserve distinct space for them, and you wouldn't be able to use the default compiler-generated copy/move constructor and assignment).

Detailed review:

> ```
> size_t size() const {
> ```

`size_t` is in the `std` namespace, and you need to include one of the header files that defines it.

```
#include <cstddef>
std::size_t size() const {
```

Looking at the implementation, it might be better to write `size()` in terms of the template parameter `C`.  That would mean it could be declared `constexpr`, which could help compilers to optimise the arithmetic operators.

The arithmetic operators are all likely to overflow in use - you might want to implement some saturating arithmetic for the values to be useful in real image-processing.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you to review it again after I apply your suggestions? Or shall I ask it as a different question?

Comment: It's generally best to ask as a new question.  Two reasons: you can't expect me to still be available, and you really want more than one reviewer to give you the best range of suggestions.